# When does $a^n \equiv -1 \pmod{m}$ have a solution?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, modular-arithmetic

I know how to get solutions to $a^n \equiv 1 \pmod{m},$ but when does $a^n \equiv -1 \pmod{m}$ have a solution? My conjecture is that the order of $a$ mod $m$ must be an even number, since if $a^n \equiv -1 \pmod{m}$, we have $a^{2n} \equiv 1 \pmod{m}$, but I don't exactly know how to prove it.

Comment: Try to solve the problem first for $m$ a prime power. The case where $p=2$ is a little harder.

Answer (score 1):

Euler's criterion says if $m$ is prime, then:

$a^{\frac {m-1}2}\equiv -1\bmod m$

if $a\not\equiv x^2\bmod m $

Example: $m=11$, we can see that, for instance $a=11+4$ or generally $11k+4$ can not be candidates, take for example $a=127\equiv 6\bmod 11$, we have:

$127^{\frac{11-1}2}\equiv -1 \bmod 11$

So $(a, n)=(127, 5)$ can be a solution for $m=11$, clearly any odd power of $127^5$ also meet the condition, hence one family of solutions can be:

$(a, n)=(127, (2k+1)5=20k +5$; $k\in \mathbb N$

Note that $127^{10k}\equiv 1\bmod 11$

$\Rightarrow 127^5\equiv \pm \bmod 11$

so $n$ can be any even or odd  multiple of $5$ for $a=127$ and $m=11$  . You can use this idea for when m is not prime.